# Why are OpenNLP packages are not recognized within Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, opennlp

I am trying to use Apache OpenNLP to get city names from a file, but I am trying to use the library on a single String first. I installed Maven and OpenNLP using Eclipse Kepler, but when I tried to run the application, it gave me a bunch of errors:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class CityNames {

public String Tokens[];
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException{

    CityNames toi = new CityNames();
    String cnt;
    cnt="John is planning to specialize in Electrical Engineering in UC Berkley and pursue a career with IBM.";
    toi.tokenization(cnt);
    String cities = toi.namefind(toi.Tokens);
    String org = toi.orgfind(toi.Tokens);
    System.out.println("City name is : "+cities);
    System.out.println("organization name is: "+org);

}
    public String namefind(String cnt[]) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenNameFinderModel tnf;
    NameFinderME nf;
    String sd = "";
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-location.bin");
        tnf = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
        nf = new NameFinderME(tnf);

        Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt);

        String a[] = Span.spansToStrings(sp, cnt);
        StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        int l = a.length;

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            fd = fd.append(a[j] + "\n");

        }
        sd = fd.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sd;
}

public String orgfind(String cnt[]) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenNameFinderModel tnf;
    NameFinderME nf;
    String sd = "";
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-organization.bin");
        tnf = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
        nf = new NameFinderME(tnf);
        Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt);
        String a[] = Span.spansToStrings(sp, cnt);
        StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        int l = a.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            fd = fd.append(a[j] + "\n");

        }

        sd = fd.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sd;
}
public void tokenization(String tokens) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenizerModel tm;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-token.bin");
        tm = new TokenizerModel(is);
        Tokenizer tz = new TokenizerME(tm);
        Tokens = tz.tokenize(tokens);
        // System.out.println(Tokens[1]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

For example, `TokenNameFinderModel` could not be resolved as a type.
In my opinion, I don't think that Eclipse recognizes the OpenNLP packages.
Any suggestions?

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CityNames</groupId>
    <artifactId>CityNames</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>      
        </pluginManagement> 
    </build>
    <projectDescription>
        <name>CityNames</name>
        <comment></comment>
        <projects></projects>
        <buildSpec>
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                <arguments>
                </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
        </buildSpec>
        <natures>       
            <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        </natures>
    </projectDescription>
</project>
```

Comment: Better if you put a relevant extract of the error stack trace and even of the pom file. I use the same configuration as yours and it works fine.

Comment: sorry i am really new to this....don't understand what r u saying

Comment: I just posted my pom.xml file

Comment: the pom seems ok. On the other hand your java file doesn't define the required imports. I don't see any import line (at the beginning) relative to OpenNLP.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you *pom.xml* file, it looks you have everything you need.

If you're using Eclipse, you should be able to press `Ctrl + Shift + O` which will organize your import statements and bring in the ones that you are currently missing (ie. for the `TokenNameFinderModel` class and other OpenNLP classes).

These import statements should appear at the top of the class when you're done:

```
import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.Tokenizer;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerME;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException;
import opennlp.tools.util.Span;
```